# Socket Exception: socket closed Thrown When Reading in a Byte Array

Tags: java, sockets, stream, socketexception, instant-messaging

Firstly, I am fairly new so I'm not exactly sure what code to put here, because I think that the problem could be in a lot of different places. Regardless, I am making an instant messenger program an I am sending images. First I convert the images to byte arrays then I send them to the server, which then routs them to the client. On the server side I have some threads listening for objects of any type. This is the `run()` method for them:

```
@Override 
public void run(){      
    while(isAlive()){  
        try{
            received = input.readObject();
        }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }          
}
```

`input` is the `ObjectInputStream` and I have a getter to get the `received` Object. However, I am getting a `SocketException` on the `received = input.readObject()` line only whenever I send this byte array. Here is the stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2589)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2599)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1319)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at server.ReaderThread.run(ReaderThread.java:24)
```

So do you know what is going on. For reference, in my server class I am assigning another object to the value of `received` via the getter and then checking to see if it is a `String`, `byte[]`, etc. using `instanceof` (if that is at all relevant). Fairly similar version of this method worked much earlier when the instant messenger was just between a client and a server. I know I left out a lot of code; just ask and I'll edit or comment.

Here is the code in the actual server program that assigns the new Object (keep in mind `receiveds` and `lastReceiveds` are `ArrayList`s and this is running in a `for(int i = 0)` loop):

```
lastReceiveds.set(i, receiveds.get(i));
receiveds.set(i, readerThreads.get(i).getReceived());
```

And then I proceed to do a `.equals` on that element of `receiveds` and continue on processing the data.

**[EDIT]** So I have been told that I am closing my sockets, streams, etc., which is true. Here is the code that causes this (the `close()` method, which is being called, simply closes all of my sockets, streams, etc.):

```
            try{

                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
                System.out.println("Got to here");
                whileChatting();

            }catch(EOFException eofException){

                showMessage("\nERROR! CONNECTION REFUSED");
                eofException.printStackTrace();

            }finally{

                close();

            }
```

Sorry it's all so indented. It outputs `"Got to here", then runs`close()` whenever it receives an byte array.

Comment: can you post more codes?

Comment: `EOFException` does *not* mean 'connection refused'. It means the peer closed the connection, which also means there was a connection, which also means it *wasn't* refused. `ConnectException: connection refused' means 'connection refused'. Don't make up your own error messages. Use the one in the exception, or the exception itself.

Comment: Thank you. I changed that to just print the stack trace and say `ERROR! END OF FILE`

Comment: Okay it may be because of the way that I process the byte array that is causing an `IOException`

Comment: It isn't an error either. The peer s expected to disconnect some time.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that *you* closed the socket, somewhere in this code, and then continued to use it. It has nothing to do with the peer or what it sends.

You also need to catch `EOFException` separately, and break out of the loop without logging when you get it. Any other `IOException` except `SocketTimeoutException` is also fatal to the connection and should cause a break.

Comment: So I have a `close()` method that closes all of the streams down, but I know that is not being called, so could this be caused by something else going wrong like a `NullPointerException` or an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: @dsiegler19 No, it is caused by calling `close()` on the socket or any of its streams. The try-with-resources statement does this too.

Comment: Actually that last comment was a lie. Let me look into it more then edit.